How do I differentiate user interactive application windows from non-interactive?
This Windows program is supposed to be a small terminal utility that neatly stacks the windows of a running application.
The user passes in the name of the executable application that they want to do this for, and the program looks for likely processes with executable names that closely match the user's input. The user confirms the application they chose when asked, and the program stacks those windows (without giving them focus)
The Problem
The problem with this program is that it brings up and stacks ALL the windows for an application, including ones that the user is not meant to interact with (sometimes, these are hidden when the application starts). This causes problems with the desktop, and I'm not sure how to differentiate user-facing windows from other windows. Is there a set of property flags that regular windows typically use that I need to test for?
See the image below. Those windows are not really interactive like normal windows are and have strange properties.
Please excuse the length of the code, but it will compile in a Windows environment.

// C++ standard library
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Windows API
#include <Windows.h>

// Windows API helpers
#include <TlHelp32.h>

/**
 * @brief Takes a snapshot of all processes in the system and returns a vector containing each process entry.
 *
 */
static std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> getAllProcesses( ) {
    // Take the snapshot.
    HANDLE snapshotHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 ); // @Todo Handle errors.
    assert( snapshotHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE );

    // Get all the processes in the snapshot.
    PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry;
    processEntry.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );                  // Must initialize this member before iterating.
    bool noErrors = Process32First( snapshotHandle, &processEntry ); // @Todo Handle errors.
    assert( noErrors ); // For now, assume this always succeeds the first time.
    std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> result;
    result.push_back( processEntry ); // Append the first process entry.
    // Query for the next process entry.
    DWORD errorCode = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    if ( !Process32Next( snapshotHandle, &processEntry ) ) {
        errorCode = GetLastError( );
    }
    while ( errorCode != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES ) {
        result.push_back( processEntry );
        errorCode = ERROR_SUCCESS;
        if ( !Process32Next( snapshotHandle, &processEntry ) ) {
            errorCode = GetLastError( );
        }
    }

    CloseHandle( snapshotHandle );
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Returns the name of the executable file for a process.
 *
 */
static std::wstring getProcessName( PROCESSENTRY32 const& p ) {
    std::wstring result;
    size_t const nameLength = wcslen( p.szExeFile );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < nameLength; ++i ) {
        result.push_back( p.szExeFile[i] );
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Returns the ID of the process that opened a given window.
 *
 */
static DWORD getWindowProcessID( HWND windowHandle ) {
    DWORD processID = 0;
    DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId( windowHandle, &processID );
    if ( threadID == 0 ) {
        std::abort( );
    }
    return processID;
}

/**
 * @brief Determines whether a given window was opened by a given process.
 *
 * @return true if the process opened the window.
 * @return false if the process did not open the window.
 */
static bool windowOpenedByProcess( HWND windowHandle, DWORD processID ) {
    return getWindowProcessID( windowHandle ) == processID;
}

/**
 * @brief Returns a vector containing the IDs of the given processes.
 *
 */
static std::vector<DWORD> getProcessIDs( std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> const& processes ) {
    std::vector<DWORD> ids;
    for ( const PROCESSENTRY32& i : processes ) {
        ids.push_back( i.th32ProcessID );
    }
    return ids;
}

/**
 * @brief Determines whether a given window was opened by any of the given processes.
 *
 * @return true if the window was opened by one of the processes.
 * @return false if the window was not opened by any of the processes.
 */
static bool windowOpenedByProcessAnyOf( HWND windowHandle, std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> const& processes ) {
    std::vector<DWORD> processIDs = getProcessIDs( processes );
    for ( const DWORD& i : processIDs ) {
        if ( windowOpenedByProcess( windowHandle, i ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @brief Returns a string where all alphabetic characters in the given string have been demoted to lowercase.
 *
 */
template <class Container, class Element> Container toLower( Container const& c ) {
    Container result;
    for ( Element const& e : c ) {
        if ( isalpha( e ) ) {
            int const lowerAsInt = tolower( e );
            // assert((lowerAsInt >= CHAR_MIN) && (lowerAsInt <= CHAR_MAX));
            result.append( 1, static_cast<Element>( lowerAsInt ) );
        } else {
            result.append( 1, e );
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Takes a vector of processes and removes the ones whose executable name does not contain the search key as a
 * substring.
 *
 */
static void filterProcessesNotContainingName( std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32>& processes, std::wstring const& searchFor ) {
    std::wstring searching = toLower<std::wstring, wchar_t>( searchFor ); // For case-insensitive search.
    size_t       count = processes.size( );
    for ( size_t i = 0; count > 0; --count ) {
        std::wstring processName = toLower<std::wstring, wchar_t>( getProcessName( processes.at( i ) ) );
        size_t       foundAt = processName.find( searching );
        if ( foundAt != std::wstring::npos ) {
            ++i; // Found a loose match. Move on to the next one.
        } else {
            processes.erase( processes.begin( ) + i ); // No match. Remove this one.
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Takes a vector of processes and removes the ones whose executable name does not exactly match the filtering
 * key.
 *
 */
static void filterProcessesNotMatchingName( std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32>& processes, std::wstring const& searchFor ) {
    size_t count = processes.size( );
    for ( size_t i = 0; count > 0; --count ) {
        if ( getProcessName( processes.at( i ) ) == searchFor ) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            processes.erase( processes.begin( ) + i );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Returns a vector containing the executable names of all given processes.
 *
 */
static std::vector<std::wstring> getProcessNames( std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> const& allProcesses ) {
    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    for ( PROCESSENTRY32 const& i : allProcesses ) {
        result.push_back( getProcessName( i ) );
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Converts a narrow string to a wide string.
 *
 */
static inline std::wstring narrowToWideString( std::string const& as ) {
    // deal with trivial case of empty string
    if ( as.empty( ) )
        return std::wstring( );

    // determine required length of new string
    size_t reqLength = ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, as.c_str( ), ( int )as.length( ), 0, 0 );

    // construct new string of required length
    std::wstring ret( reqLength, L'\0' );

    // convert old string to new string
    ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, as.c_str( ), ( int )as.length( ), &ret[0], ( int )ret.length( ) );

    // return new string ( compiler should optimize this away )
    return ret;
}

/**
 * @brief Prints a container type as a numbered list to standard output.
 *
 */
static void printNumberedList( std::set<std::wstring> const& container ) {
    int n = 1;
    for ( auto const& i : container ) {
        std::wcout << " [" << n << "]\t" << i << "\n";
        ++n;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Queries the user to select a running application from a list of possible applications.
 *
 * @note This function makes the assumption that similarly named executable names all belong to the same application.
 */
static void userSelectApplication( std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32>& processes ) {
    std::set<std::wstring> uniqueProcessNames;
    for ( std::wstring const& i : getProcessNames( processes ) ) {
        uniqueProcessNames.insert( i );
    }
    std::wcout << "Found " << uniqueProcessNames.size( ) << " possible application(s)..." << std::endl << std::endl;
    printNumberedList( uniqueProcessNames );
    std::wcout << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Please select the desired application..." << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "> ";

    // @Todo Handle out-of-bounds access.
    size_t selection = 0;
    std::cin >> selection;
    std::vector<std::wstring> uniqueProcessNamesAsVector{ uniqueProcessNames.begin( ), uniqueProcessNames.end( ) };
    filterProcessesNotMatchingName( processes, uniqueProcessNamesAsVector.at( selection - 1 ) );
}

/**
 * @brief Given an executable name as a loose search key, returns a vector of processes whose executable name matches.
 *
 * @details First, a loose search is formed. If the loose succeeds, the user is prompted to select the exact executable.
 * If the loose search fails, then there were no possible search results for the given executable name.
 *
 */
static std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> findApplication( std::wstring const& executableName ) {
    std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> processes = getAllProcesses( );
    filterProcessesNotContainingName( processes, executableName );
    if ( !processes.empty( ) ) {
        userSelectApplication( processes );
    }
    return processes;
}

/**
 * @brief Returns the title of a window.
 *
 * @note The returned string may be empty if the window has no text for the title or for other reasons.
 */
static std::wstring getWindowTitle( HWND windowHandle ) {
    SetLastError( 0 );
    int   titleLength = GetWindowTextLength( windowHandle );
    DWORD error = GetLastError( );
    if ( titleLength == 0 && GetLastError( ) != 0 ) {
        std::abort( );
    }
    wchar_t* title = new wchar_t[titleLength + 1];
    int      copied = GetWindowText( windowHandle, title, titleLength + 1 );
    if ( copied == 0 && GetLastError( ) != 0 ) {
        delete[] title;
        std::abort( );
    }
    assert( copied == titleLength );
    std::wstring result{ title };
    delete[] title;
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Returns a vector of window titles as strings for a vector of windows.
 *
 */
static std::vector<std::wstring> getWindowTitles( std::vector<HWND> const& windowHandles ) {
    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    for ( auto const& i : windowHandles ) {
        result.push_back( getWindowTitle( i ) );
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Callback used to enumerate all top-level windows.
 *
 */
static BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsCallback( HWND windowHandle, LPARAM parameter ) {
    std::vector<HWND>* pHandles = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>( parameter );
    ( *pHandles ).push_back( windowHandle );
    return true;
}

/**
 * @brief Takes a vector of handles to windows and removes those whose window was not opened by a given process.
 *
 */
static void filterWindowsNotOpenedByProcesses( std::vector<HWND>&                 windowHandles,
                                               std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> const& processes ) {
    size_t count = windowHandles.size( );
    for ( size_t i = 0; count > 0; --count ) {
        if ( windowOpenedByProcessAnyOf( windowHandles.at( i ), processes ) ) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            windowHandles.erase( windowHandles.begin( ) + i );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Takes a vector of handles to windows and removes those that have no text for their title.
 *
 */
static void filterUnnamedWindows( std::vector<HWND>& windowHandles ) {
    size_t count = windowHandles.size( );
    for ( size_t i = 0; count > 0; --count ) {
        if ( !getWindowTitle( windowHandles.at( i ) ).empty( ) ) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            windowHandles.erase( windowHandles.begin( ) + i );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Takes a vector of handles to windows and puts each owned window in a "show" state, but does not activate them.
 *
 */
static void showAllWindows( std::vector<HWND>& windowHandles ) {
    for ( auto& i : windowHandles ) {
        ShowWindow( i, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE );
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Takes a vector of handles to windows and stacks all owned windows over top one another.
 *
 */
static BOOL stackWindows( std::vector<HWND>& windowHandles ) {
    int const windowLength = 500;
    int const windowHeight = 300;
    // POINT     windowSize = { windowLength, windowHeight };

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    // POINT startPosition = { x, y };

    int const incLeft = 30;
    int const incDown = 20;

    UINT const options = SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOACTIVATE;
    BOOL       noErrors = true;
    for ( auto& i : windowHandles ) {
        noErrors = noErrors && SetWindowPos( i, HWND_TOP, x, y, windowLength, windowHeight, options );
        x += incLeft;
        y += incDown;
    }

    return noErrors;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    if ( argc == 1 ) {
        std::cout << "Not enough arguments.\n";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else if ( argc > 2 ) {
        std::cout << "Too many arguments.\n";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_U16TEXT ); // Set output to unicode mode for wide text strings.
    std::string const           userInput{ argv[1] };
    std::wstring const          executableName = narrowToWideString( userInput );
    std::vector<PROCESSENTRY32> processes = findApplication( executableName );

    if ( processes.empty( ) ) {
        std::cout << "No applications found.\n";
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    // Enumerate all top-level windows.
    std::vector<HWND> windowHandles;
    EnumWindows( &enumWindowsCallback, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>( &windowHandles ) );

    filterWindowsNotOpenedByProcesses( windowHandles, processes );
    filterUnnamedWindows( windowHandles ); // Weed out windows not likely to be user-facing, interactive windows.
    showAllWindows( windowHandles );
    stackWindows( windowHandles );

    return 0;
}


One obvious thing to try is to ignore windows which aren't visible

Might be useful https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606

As others have commented, the solution was to check for any windows belonging to a process that weren't visible and ignore those, while showing the others.
This was achieved by using the function IsWindowVisible(...).

If you've solved the issue, please do not forget the accept it as answer.
